Templated function yields errors if it is in .cpp file
I am writing a C++ code split in multiple files, and I want to include a function my_function in a .h file.
Here is the file structure:

main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include "library.h"

int main() {

    int i=0;

    my_function(i);


    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}


in library.h I include the predeclaration of my_function:
#ifndef library_h
#define library_h

#include <stdio.h>

void my_function(int);

#endif 


and my_function  is coded into library.cpp:
#include "library.h"


void my_function(int i){

    int j;

    j=i+1;

}



I compile with g++ library.cpp main.cpp -o main.o  and the compilation returns no errors. So far, so good.
The issue:
However, if I want my_function to take a template argument and I modify the files as follows:

main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include "library.h"

int main() {

    int i=0;

    my_function<int>(i);

    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}



library.h:
#ifndef library_h
#define library_h

#include <stdio.h>

template<class T> void my_function(T);

#endif 


library.cpp:
#include "library.h"

template<class T> void my_function(T i){

    T j;

    j=i+1;

}



I get a compilation error:
 % g++ library.cpp main.cpp -o main.o
ld: Undefined symbols:
  void my_function<int>(int), referenced from:
      _main in main-2d776a.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Why ? How may I fix this? I do see that a similar issue has been addressed here, but I am not sure that it answers the question in my specific case.
Thank you

You are forward declaring it as a normal function.  It is not a normal function.  it is a template function.  If you want to forward declare a function template.   e.g.
template <typename T> void my_function(T);

The question you linked is exactly the issue you are having.

One way: Explicit template instantiation. Another way: definition of template in header/include file. Both in the post you linked.

Minor point: "I include the predeclaration of my_function" -- that's a declaration of my_function. There's no such thing as a predeclaration. Basically, there are declarations (which announce the presence of a name) and there are definitions (which define the name and also, naturally, act as declarations).

@Joe your solution does not work, it yields the same compilation error that I posted.

its no solution, they merely pointed out that void my_function(int); does not declare a template

That is not a compilation error.  It is a linker error.    Before it was giving you the error because you declared a function that you never instantiated (the non-template one). Now it is giving you an error because, while you have correctly now told the compiler what you are calling, you have failed to explicitly instantiate the template for the linker to see
